# Modifying y-axis in histogram in Pandas matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have 33960 - 0's and 144 - 1's in `data_train['fk_action_code_id']`.

On plotting histogram, the bar of 1 is so less that it is not visible. Is there any way I can raise the bar of 1 by modifying the Y-Axis so that the bar of 1 is visible?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
b=[0,145, 35000]
plt.yticks(b)
plt.hist(data_train['fk_action_code_id'], histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions: you could

1.) create two y axes, one for the zeros and the other for the ones

2.) multiply one of the bars by a numerical factor, so that they are of the same order of magnitude (you should explain this in the plot legend then)

3.) draw a logarithmic histogram with the option `log=True` in the `plt.hist()` command.

The following will produce plots for these three options:

[image: Multiplied][image: Logarithmic][image: twin axes]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
zeros = np.zeros([35000])
modifier = 100
ones = np.ones([145*modifier])
arr = np.hstack((zeros, ones))
bins = np.asarray([-0.5, 0.5, 1.5])
plt.hist(arr, bins=bins, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75, log=False)
plt.xticks([0,1])
plt.title('Multiplied with a factor')
plt.savefig('multiplied.png')
plt.show()
plt.clf()
modifier = 1
ones = np.ones([145*modifier])
arr = np.hstack((zeros, ones))
plt.hist(arr, bins=bins, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75, log=True)
plt.xticks([0,1])
plt.title('Logarithmic')
plt.savefig('log.png')
plt.show()
plt.clf()

ax1 = plt.gca()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_yticks([0, 35000, 40000])
ax1.set_ylim(0, 40000)
ax2.set_yticks([0, 145, 200])
ax2.set_ylim(0, 200)
ax1.hist(arr, bins=[bins[0], bins[1]], facecolor='green', alpha=0.75, log=False)#, histtype='bar')#, rwidth=1.0)
ax2.hist(arr, bins=[bins[1], bins[2]], facecolor='green', alpha=0.75, log=False)#, histtype='bar')#, rwidth=1.0)
plt.xticks([0,1])
plt.title('Two y axes')
plt.savefig('two_axes.png')
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```